# How to link to specified page of an outer pdf document?

Tags: hyperref

Recently, I made a beamer presentation and I want to link to a pdf I have made before, but I can only link to the first page of pdf document using the command:

```
\href{doc/mydoc.pdf}{thedoc}
```

and I want to link to a specific page. 
Someone told me to use

```
\href{doc/mydoc.pdf#page.5}{thedoc}
```

or

```
\href{doc/mydoc.pdf#page=5}{thedoc}
```

but they don't work.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What did you do to the commas? They look rather strange.

Comment: @Caramdir: that was weird; the commas _and the apparent spaces_ were a single character.  Replacing them with ', ' fixed the display.  I also cleaned up the layout and language while I was at it - hope that it's okay and that I haven't changed the meaning of the question.

Comment: Similar question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11520/pdfpages-and-linktodoc/11522#11522

Comment: \href{doc/mydoc.pdf\#page.5}{thedoc}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All `hyperref`/pdfLaTeX can do is insert a link of a certain form. It's up to the PDF viewer what to do with that link, and I don’t think there’s a standard link format for pages of external PDF files. Even if some viewers have implemented something for this, it wouldn’t be a robust solution.

My suggestion would be to actually include the linked-to PDF in the PDF you’re creating, and then you can use features of the [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) package to insert hyperlink targets for the included pages, and then you can use internal links. A quick example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Here's a \hyperlink{included.pdf.2}{link to to page 2 of the included pdf}.
\includepdf[pages=1-5,link=true]{included.pdf}
\end{document}
```

With `beamer`, at the end, you probably want something like:

```
{
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
\includepdf[pages=1-5,link=true,fitpaper]{included.pdf}
}
```

so that the included PDF fits the paper size of the original for the included pages, and `beamer`'s background color and navigation bars are suppressed on those pages.

Comment: Thank  you，It  must include the page in the beamer。
so  it is not the best。 Thank you  too!

Answer (score 17):

Meanwhile package `hyperref` (must be loaded) has changed and allows now links to a special page of a pdf files with the command:

```
\href[page=5]{./doc/mydoc.pdf}{thedoc, page 5}
```

If you click the link "thedoc, page 5" your file `mydoc.pdf` is showed starting with page 5.

Comment: Does this work only if the document is compiled using `pdflatex`, and that the external pdf document is saved in one's hard drive? I've tried linking to a document hosted on a website (my default browser is Chrome), but it still opens to the first page. Also, when I compile using Bakoma, which doesn't use pdflatex, this trick doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I'm guessing that the file's path is given in the curly brackets. How do I add a full file path?

Answer (score 5):

Try `\hyperref{doc/mydoc.pdf}{page}{5}{thedoc}.`

Comment: It doesn't work.
Does it need special package?
Or  the pdf  need a special process.

Comment: Which pdf viewer are you using? This will probably not work with every viewer.

Comment: The target PDF also needs to support this. So if it is a LaTeX document it must be compiled with hyperref enabled.

Comment: It seems to work in adobe reader, not in evince.  I am compiling with pdflatex. You need to load the hyperref package, but beamer should be doing that for you.

Comment: I use Adove Reader 9， I have tried it several times ，all failed。

Comment: Did you compile **both** documents with hyperref? (Also, please fix your punctuation.)

Comment: Both ？ Sometimes pdf document is without latex source，How to do？

Comment: I don't really know anything about the internals of PDFs, but as far as I understand it one cannot link to a page. Instead one links to a target mark called `page.no`. Apparently not all PDF generators include those.

Comment: (One more time: I do not know how you manage to do that, but the punctuation symbols in your comments look "abnormal".)

Comment: You can probably add the page.no mark to a pdf file using something like pdftk (http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/).