# Links to pages located after

Tags: links

I am linking to pages.
I can refer to pages that are located before, but I can’t link to page 3 to find two on page. Why is that? How to fix? thank!

```
  \documentclass[a4paper]{article} % Размер бумаги и стиль документа (книга, журнал,...)
    \usepackage[14pt]{extsizes} % Размер шрифта
    \usepackage{cmap} % поиск в PDF
    \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} % кодировка
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % кодировка исходного текста
    \usepackage[english,russian]{babel} %локализация и переносы
    \usepackage{caption}
       
    % подключаем hyperref (для ссылок внутри  pdf)
    \usepackage[unicode, pdftex, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
    %\newcommand{\стр}[1]{стр.~\pageref{#1}}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    Здесь описан процесс создания ссылки\label{L} подробно описан здесь.
        \newpage
    как мы уже отмечали на стр.~\pageref{L} говорится о...
    Однако, как будет показано далее, на стр..~\pageref{units} это всё неправда.
    
    
    \newpage 
    Однако здесь\label{units} сказано совершенно о другом.
        
    \end{document}
```

Comment: More people here will be able to understand and help you if you post in English.

Comment: Have you compiled more than once?

Comment: I see that the hyperref links for `\pageref` are the same as for `\ref`, and so take you to the section heading, or the first page. (The problem is not forward versus backward.) Maybe somebody has advice that fixes this hyperref problem.

Comment: Similarly, I always get to the first page. It turns out the links do not work at all.

Comment: the command \pageref works correctly, and indicates the desired page, but the link doesn’t work correctly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be nice if \pageref would automatically jump to the right page. But the current label/ref system of LaTeX is a bit restricted. hyperref can store only one destination name and this is used for the current counter, so there is no place for the page destination.

So currently you can either add `\phantomsection` before your \label, then the link will jump to this position:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
  \begin{document}

 first page

 wrong: \pageref{units}, right: \pageref{units2}
 \newpage
 second page  \label{units}\phantomsection\label{units2}

 \end{document}
```

Or with an extended reference system like zref one could also store the page destination:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}     
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \usepackage{zref-base,zref-user}
 \makeatletter
 \zref@newprop*{pagedest}[Doc-Start]{page.\@the@H@page}
 \zref@addprop{main}{pagedest}
 \newcommand\hyperpageref[1]{\hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{pagedest}}{\pageref*{#1}}}
 \makeatother
 \begin{document}
 
 first page 
 
 wrong: \pageref{units}, right: \hyperpageref{units}
 \newpage
 second page  \label{units}\zlabel{units}

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

By default you cannot simply use `\label` to mark a label on page without any previous counter stepping. `hyperref` do creates one pdf link for every page, but the position of those links are always located at the upper-left corner of page. See [an example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1849).

Therefore to allow variable link position and auto page reference, here I create a dummy counter `@page` stepped by new command `\pagelabel`. You can use `\pagelabel{<label name>}` to create a "label on page", and then use `\pageref{<label name>}` to refer to it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % Размер бумаги и стиль документа (книга, журнал,...)
\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes} % Размер шрифта
\usepackage{cmap} % поиск в PDF
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} % кодировка
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % кодировка исходного текста
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} %локализация и переносы
\usepackage{caption}
   
% подключаем hyperref (для ссылок внутри  pdf)
\usepackage[unicode, pdftex, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
%\newcommand{\стр}[1]{стр.~\pageref{#1}}

\newcounter{@page}
\newcommand*{\pagelabel}{\refstepcounter{@page}\label}

\begin{document}
Здесь описан процесс создания ссылки\pagelabel{L} подробно описан здесь.
\newpage

как мы уже отмечали на стр.~\pageref{L} говорится о...
Однако, как будет показано далее, на стр..~\pageref{units} это всё неправда.
\newpage

Однако здесь \pagelabel{units}сказано совершенно о другом.    
\end{document}
```