# nameref sectioning: Parameters must be numbered consecurivel

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, nameref, crossreftools

After the latest updates to TeXLive 2020, a book-length document using the `memoir` document class now fails to compile with either pdflatex or xelatex, despite my having made no changes whatsoever in the sources.

**What package(s) broke things, and what is the fix?**

I'm hard pressed to know where to begin to diagnose the problem! Here's an excerpt from the log:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2019/09/16 v2.46 Cross-referencing by name of section

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.s
ty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count655
)
Redoing nameref's sectioning
./topology.tex:99: Parameters must be numbered consecutively.
<to be read again> 
                   ##
l.99 \begin{document}

I've inserted the digit you should have used after the #.
Type `1' to delete what you did use.
```

The log file shows many, many repeats of that same `nameref` error.

The error is occurring during processing of my many files that are input to the preamble. The preamble does *not* explicitly load the `nameref` package, so I presume this is being loaded by `hyperref` or another cross-reference-related package.

These preamble files include the following one for cross-referencing, which is presumably the offending one:

```
% LINKS.STY - Indexing, cross-referencing, & hyperlinks 
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2020/02/02]
\ProvidesPackage{preamble/links}[2020-09-29  
Indexing, cross-referencing, & hyperlinks]

% LOADS packages 
%   biblatex.sty, nomencl.sty,
%   xurl.sty, 
%   doclicense.sty, hyperxmp.sty,
%   hyperref.sty,
%   xassoccnt.sty, zref.sty
%   aliascnt.sty,
%   cleveref.sty,
%   crossreftools.sty
%
% SWITCHES USED: colorsecs, washthms

%% BIBLIOGRAPHY
\RequirePackage[
  backend=bibtex,
  %backend=biber,
  bibstyle=mybooknumeric,
  citestyle=numeric,
  dashed=true,
  defernumbers=true,
  urldate=iso,date=iso,seconds=true]%
{biblatex} 
%
\addbibresource{topologyref.bib}
\addbibresource{topologyread.bib}
%
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{7000}% was 9999
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{8000}

%% NOTATION INDEX
\RequirePackage[refpage,norefeq,intoc,english,cfg]{nomencl}

%% INDEXING COMMANDS
\newcommand{\indexemph}{\textbf} % definition or main location
\newcommand{\nn}[1]{{#1}n}
\newcommand{\figidx}[1]{{#1}fig}

\providecommand\gobbleone[1]{}
\newcommand{\seeonly}[2]{\, (\emph{\seename} #1)}
\newcommand{\also}[2]{\unskip\emph{\alsoname} #1}
\newcommand{\Also}[2]{\unskip\emph{See also} #1}
% Fix error re entries in index page header
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/332098/13492
\def\indexsee#1{\indexseeI#1@\end}
\def\indexseeI#1@#2\end{%
  \def\temp{#2}%
  \ifx\temp\empty
    \def\next{\indexseeIII{#1}{#1}}%
  \else
    \def\next{\indexseeII#1@#2\end}%
  \fi
  \next
}
\def\indexseeII#1@#2@\end{\indexseeIII{#1}{#2}}
\def\indexseeIII#1#2#3{\index{#1@#2\protect\gobbleone|seeonly{#3}}}
\newcommand{\indexalso}[2]{\index{#1!zzzz@\protect\gobbleone|also{#2}}}
\newcommand{\indexAlso}[2]{\index{#1!zzzz@\protect\gobbleone|Also{#2}}}
%% try this
\newcommand{\indexnamesee}[2]{\index[names]{#1\protect\gobbleone|seeonly{#2}}}
% ...fix for memoir to put hyperlink on mainref, too:
\newcommand{\mainref}[1]{\textbf{\emph{\hyperpage{#1}}}}
%%  END INDEXING

%%  CROSS-REFERENCING
\RequirePackage{xurl}   % new: break URL anywhere

\RequirePackage[type={CC},modifier={by-nc-nd},version={4.0},lang={english}]{doclicense}%

\RequirePackage{hyperxmp} % to add metadata info into pdf
\usepackage[pdfa]{hyperref}%
\hypersetup{
  pdfapart=2, pdfaconformance=u,
  bookmarksnumbered,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=3,
  breaklinks=true,
  colorlinks, citecolor=red, filecolor=defaultcolor, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue,
  linktocpage=true,linktoc=all,
  pdftitle={Topology, Second Edition},
  pdfauthor={Murray Eisenberg},pdfcreator={Murray Eisenberg},
  pdfauthortitle={Professor Emeritus, University of Massachusetts Amherst},
  pdfcontactemail={murray@math.umass.edu},
  pdfcontacturl={https://www.math.umass.edu/directory/emeritus-faculty/murray-eisenberg},
  pdfpublisher={Murray Eissenberg},
  pdfdate={\today},
  pdflang={en},pdfmetalang={en},
  pdfpubtype={Book},
  pdfsubject={topology},
  pdfkeywords={topology, general topology,topological space,metric space,compact space,connected space,continuity,convergence},
  pdfcopyright={Copyright (C) 2020, Murray Eisenberg},
  pdflicenseurl={http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/},
}%
\ifTUTeX
  % no further glyph info needed
\else
  \input{glyphtounicode}
  \pdfgentounicode=1
  \pdfglyphtounicode{EM}{0058 0058 0058 0058 0058 0058 0058 0058}%
  \pdfglyphtounicode{NUL}{0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060}%
  \pdfglyphtounicode{uni222B.dsp}{222B}%
  \pdfglyphtounicode{summationdisplay.1}{0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060}%
  \pdfglyphtounicode{summationdisplay}{0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060}%    
  \pdfglyphtounicode{radicalBigg}{0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060}%
  \pdfglyphtounicode{radicalbig}{0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060}%
  \pdfglyphtounicode{radicalbigg}{0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060}%
   \immediate\pdfobj stream attr{/N 3} file{sRGB.icc}
   \pdfcatalog{%
     /OutputIntents [ <<
     /Type /OutputIntent
     /S /GTS_PDFA1
     /DestOutputProfile \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R
     /OutputConditionIdentifier (sRGB v4)
     /Info (sRGB)
         >> ]
    } 
\fi

% Allow link to page with label -- patch by Martin Scharrer
% cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19416/9237
\let\orig@Hy@EveryPageAnchor\Hy@EveryPageAnchor
\def\Hy@EveryPageAnchor{%
    \begingroup
    \hypersetup{pdfview=Fit}%
    \orig@Hy@EveryPageAnchor
    \endgroup
}
% My commands to use that
% Usage: \pagereftext{text-to-appar-in-link}{lbl} with usual \label{lbl} for target.
\newcommand{\pagereftext}[2]{\hyperlink{page.\getpagerefnumber{#2}}{#1} on \cpageref{#2}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\pagereftext*[2]{\hyperlink{page.\getpagerefnumber{#2}}{#1}}

% HYPERREF FIXES - not needed: using \CC for complexes!
 \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{% then...
  %%% Redo, from mismath: % Not needed!
  \let\mafx@old@dot=\.
  \def\mafx@dot@skip{\thinmuskip}
  \def\mafx@dot{\mskip\mafx@dot@skip}
  \def\mafx@per@dot{\begingroup\ifmmode\def\mafx@tmp{\mafx@dot}\else%
  \def\mafx@tmp{\mafx@old@dot}\fi\expandafter\endgroup\mafx@tmp}
  %
  \let\.=\mafx@per@dot}
  {}

\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypersetup{hidelinks}}}

%MUST NOT explicitly load showidx except within the Oberdiek hack, below.
%\RequirePackage{showidx} % already loaded in root .tex file
%Begin the ``quick and dirty hack'' due to Heiko Oberdiek which loads showidx
\ifHy@hyperindex
  \def\HyInd@ParenLeft{(}%
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex
  \let\HyInd@showidx\@empty
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex for package showidx
  \def\HyInd@showidx#1{%
    \@showidx{#1}%
    \if@nobreak
      \ifvmode
        \nobrak
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
% Load package showidx
  \let\siOrg@makeindex\makeindex
  \let\siOrg@@index\@index
  \let\siOrg@@wrindex\@wrindex
  \let\siOrg@index\index
  \RequirePackage{showidx}
  \let\makeindex\siOrg@makeindex
  \let\@index\siOrg@@index
  \let\@wrindex\siOrg@@wrindex
  \let\index\siOrg@index
% rest of hyperref part
  \@ifpackageloaded{multind}{%
    \let\HyInd@org@wrindex\@wrindex
    \def\@wrindex#1#2{\HyInd@@wrindex{#1}#2||\\}%
    \def\HyInd@@wrindex#1#2|#3|#4\\{%
      \ifx\\#3\\%
        \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|hyperpage}%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#3}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3hyperpage}%
        \else
          \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3}%
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
  }{%
    \def\@wrindex#1{\@@wrindex#1||\\}
    \def\@@wrindex#1|#2|#3\\{%
      \ifx\\#2\\%
        \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
          \string\indexentry{#1|hyperpage}{\thepage}%
        }%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#2}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
             \string\indexentry{#1|#2hyperpage}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \else
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
            \string\indexentry{#1|#2}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \fi
      \fi
      \endgroup
      \HyInd@showidx{#1}%
      \@esphack
    }%
  }%
\fi
%End the ``quick and dirty hack'' due to Heiko Oberdiek which loads showidx 

%% Allow ref to section n, not section m.n
% From "trickier version" by Christian Hupfer
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383608/13492
\let\@xp\expandafter
%
% Stripping the dot from the 1.2 -like reference
\def\@@stripdot#1.#2\@nil{#2}
%
% Stripping the memoir stuff from the reference, i.e. \M@TitleReference {1.2}{FOO} and handing #1 (1.2) over to the \@@stripdot macro
\def\@stripdot\M@TitleReference #1#2\@nil{\@@stripdot#1\@nil}
%
%Macro, second level of expansion
\newcommand{\stripdot}[1]{%
  \@xp\@stripdot#1\@nil
}
\newcommand{\crefsec}[1]{%
  % Expand the argument first
  \IfRefUndefinedExpandable{#1}{%
    % Do nothing if #1 is not defined
  }{%
    \hyperlink{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{anchor}{}}{\@xp\stripdot\@xp{\getrefnumber{#1}}}%
  }%
}

% Another way to link to page - Ulrike Fischer
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/549807/13492
% Usage: \zlabel{lbl} on target, \hyperpageref{lbl} for link
\usepackage[user,hyperref]{zref}%{zref-base,zref-user}
 \zref@newprop*{pagedest}[Doc-Start]{page.\@the@H@page}
 \zref@addprop{main}{pagedest}
 \newcommand\hyperpageref[1]{\hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{pagedest}}{\pageref*{#1}}}
% Fix capitalization of named theorems, etc., in list of theorems
\def\ll@theorem{%
  \protect\numberline{\csname the\thmt@envname\endcsname}%
  \ifx\@empty\thmt@shortoptarg
    \thmt@thmname
  \else
    \protect\makefirstuc{\thmt@shortoptarg}%
  \fi}
\def\l@thmt@theorem{}
%
\let\ll@proposition=\ll@theorem
\let\ll@corollary=\ll@theorem
\let\ll@lemma=\ll@theorem

\RequirePackage{aliascnt}
\RequirePackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}
% Fix missing Oxford comma:
\newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{, and\nobreakspace}

\RequirePackage{crossreftools}
% Fix to crossreftools
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512175/13492
\renewcommand{\@@crtextr@ct@ref}[2]{%
  \expandafter\@@@crtextr@ct@ref\expandafter{\detokenize{#2}}{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\@@@crtextr@ct@ref}[2]{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname r@#1\endcsname\relax
  \crt@refundefined%
  \else
  \expandafter\expandafter\csname crt@ref@splitter@#2\endcsname\csname r@#1\endcsname%
  \fi
}

\crtlistoflabelsstructurelevel{chapter}

% cref names and formats:
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}
\crefname{page}{page}{pages}
\Crefname{Page}{Page}{Pages}
\crefname{theorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\Crefname{theorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\crefname{namedtheorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\Crefname{namedtheorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\crefname{namedproposition}{Proposition}{Propositions}
\Crefname{namedproposition}{Proposition}{Propositions}
\crefname{namedlemma}{Lemma}{Lemmas}
\Crefname{namedlemma}{Lemma}{Lemmas}
\crefname{proposition}{Proposition}{Propositions}
\Crefname{proposition}{Proposition}{Propositions}
\crefname{corollary}{Corollary}{Corollaries}
\Crefname{corollary}{Corollary}{Corollaries}
\crefname{namedcorollary}{Corollary}{Corollaries}
\Crefname{namedcorollary}{Corollary}{Corollaries}
\crefname{axiom}{Axiom}{Axioms}
\Crefname{axiom}{Axiom}{Axioms}
% need namedaxiom??
\crefname{convention}{Convention}{Conventions}
\Crefname{convention}{Convention}{Conventins}
\crefname{figure}{Figure}{Figures}
\Crefname{figure}{Figure}{Figures}
\crefname{table}{Table}{Tables}
\Crefname{table}{Table}{Tables}
\crefname{example}{Example}{Examples}
\Crefname{example}{Example}{Examples}
\crefname{continuedexample}{Example}{Examples}
\Crefname{continuedexample}{Example}{Examples}
\crefname{examples}{Examples}{Examples}
\Crefname{examples}{Examples}{Examples}
\crefname{examples}{Examples}{Examples}
\Crefname{examples}{Examples}{Examples}
\crefname{exampleaux}{Example}{Examples}    % since example is envir not thm type
\Crefname{exampleaux}{Example}{Examples}
\crefname{application}{Application}{Applications}
\Crefname{application}{Application}{Applications}
\crefname{standingassumption}{Standing Assumption}{Standing Assumptions}
\Crefname{standingassumption}{Standing Assumption}{Standing Assumptions}
\crefformat{pfstepsi}{#2Step~#1#3}
\crefname{equation}{equation}{equations}
\Crefname{equation}{Equation}{Equations}
\crefname{problemsenumi}{Exercise}{Exercises}
\crefformat{problemsenumi}{#2Exercise~#1#3}
\Crefformat{problemsenumi}{#2Exercise~#1#3}
\crefformat{problempartsenumi}{#2#1#3}
\Crefformat{problempartsenumi}{#2#1#3}
\crefformat{problemscontent}{#2\textnormal{#3}}
\Crefformat{problemscontent}{#2\textnormal{#3}}
\crefname{topic}{}{}
\Crefname{topic}{}{}
\crefname{subtopic}{}{}
\Crefname{subtopic}{}{}
\crefformat{subtopic}{#2``#1''#3} % for my unnumbered subtopics
\Crefformat{subtopic}{#2``#1''#3} % ditto, capitalized
\crefname{enumi}{}{} % do not use ``Item''
\crefname{enumii}{}{}
\crefname{penumi}{}{} % do not use ``Item''
\crefname{penumii}{}{}
\crefformat{penumi}{(#2#1#3)}
\Crefformat{penumi}{(#2#1#3)}
\crefformat{penumi}{\textup{(#2#1#3)}}
\crefrangeformat{penumi}{\textup{(#3#1#4)}--\textup{(#5#2#6)}}
\crefformat{penumprimei}{(#2#1#3)}
\Crefformat{penumprimei}{(#2#1#3)}
\crefname{romenumi}{}{}
\Crefname{romenumi}{}{}
\crefname{pexenumi}{Example}{Examples}
\crefformat{pexenumi}{\textup{(#2#1#3)}}
\crefrangeformat{pexenumi}{\textup{(#3#1#4)}--\textup{(#5#2#6)}}
\crefname{proplis}{}{}
\Crefname{proplis}{}{}
\crefformat{proplisi}{#2#1#3}
\crefrangeformat{proplisi}{\textup{#3#1#4}--\textup{#5#2#6}}
\crefname{numcasesi}{Case}{Cases}
\Crefname{numcasesi}{Case}{Cases}
\crefname{romcasesi}{Case}{Cases}
\Crefname{romcasesi}{Case}{Cases}
\crefname{alphcasesi}{Case}{Cases}
\Crefname{alphcasesi}{Case}{Cases}
\crefname{chapter}{Chapter}{Chapters}
\crefname{section}{Section}{Sections}
\crefname{pdefenumi}{Definition}{Definitions}
\crefformat{pdefenumi}{\textup{(#2#1#3)}}
\crefname{subsec}{subsection}{subsections}
\Crefname{subsec}{Subsection}{Subsections}
\crefformat{subsec}{#2subsection~``#1''#3} % for my unnumbered subsections
\Crefformat{subsec}{#2Subsection~``#1''#3} % ditto, capitalized
\crefmultiformat{subsec}{subsections~``#2#1#3''}{ and~``#2#1#3''}{,~``#2#1#3''}{ and~``#2#1#3''}

% Special handling of cref's...
\newcommand\crefthmpart[2]{\cref{#1}~\cref{#2}}
\newcommand\crefdef[2]{\namecref{#2}~\labelcref{#1}~\cref{#2}}
\newcommand\crefex[2]{\namecref{#2}~\labelcref{#1}~\cref{#2}}
\newcommand\Crefex[2]{\nameCref{#2}~\labelcref{#1}~\cref{#2}}
\newcommand\crefexone[1]{Example~\cref{#1}}
\newcommand\refex[2]{\namecref{#2}~\labelcref{#1}~\cref{#2}}
\newcommand\crefrangeex[3]{\cref{#1}~\crefrange{#2}{#3}}
\newcommand\Crefrangeex[3]{\Cref{#1}~\crefrange{#2}{#3}}
% special handling of problems environment
\newcommand\crefprob[2]{\cref{#1}~\ref{#2}}
\newcommand\crefrangeprob[2]{Exercises~\textup{\ref{#1}}--\textup{\ref{#2}}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\crefrangeprob*[2]{\textup{\ref{#1}}--\textup{\ref{#2}}}
\newcommand\crefrangeprobpart[2]{\textup{\ref{#1}}--\textup{\ref{#2}}}
\newcommand\crefprobandrangeprobpart[3]{\cref{#1}~\textup{\ref{#2}}--\textup{\ref{#3}}}

% Allow names in cross-reference to named theorem
\newcommand{\crefthm}[1]{%
  \IfStrEqCase*{\crtcrefcounter{#1}}{%
    {namedtheorem}{\crefthmname{#1}~(\ref{#1})}%
    {namedtproposition}{\crefthmname{#1}~(\ref{#1})}%
    {namedlemma}{\crefthmname{#1}~(\ref{#1})}%
    {namedaxiom}{\crefthmname{#1}~(\ref{#1})}%
    }%
    [\crefthmname{#1}~(\cref{#1})]%
}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\crefthm*[1]{%
  \IfStrEqCase*{\crtcrefcounter{#1}}{%
    {namedtheorem}{\crefthmname*{#1}~(\ref{#1})}%
    {namedproposition}{\crefthmname*{#1}~(\ref{#1})}%
    {namedlemma}{\crefthmname*{#1}~(\ref{#1})}%
    {namedaxiom}{\crefthmname*{#1}~(\ref{#1})}%
    }%
    [\crefthmname*{#1}~(\cref{#1})]%
}
%
% For upper-casing, i.e., leave names as is:
\newcommand{\crefthmname}[1]{\hyperlink{\crtrefanchor{#1}}{\crtrefname{#1}}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\crefthmname*[1]{\crtrefname{#1}}
\newcommand{\Crefthmname}[1]{\hyperlink{\crtrefanchor{#1}}{\crtrefname{#1}}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\Crefthmname*[1]{\crtrefname{#1}}

\newcommand\crefthmnamed[2]{\crefthm{#1}~\cref{#2}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\crefthmnamed*[2]{\crefthm*{#1}~\cref{#2}}

% Allow names in cross-reference to chapters, sections, subsections
\newcommand*{\crefunit}[1]{\cref{#1} (\nameref*{#1})}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\crefunit*[1]{\cref*{#1} (\nameref*{#1})}
\newcommand*{\crefunitname}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\nameref{#1}}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\crefunitname*[1]{\nameref*{#1}}

% Need special ref command for subsecs since they're not numbered
\newcommand*{\crefsubsec}[1]{\cref{#1} (\cpageref{#1})}
\newcommand*{\Crefsubsec}[1]{\Cref{#1} (\cpageref{#1})}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\crefsubsec*[1]{\cref*{#1} (\cpageref{#1})}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\Crefsubsec*[1]{\Cref*{#1} (\cpageref{#1})}

% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/reference-name-of-description-list-item-in-latex
\def\namedlabel#1#2{\begingroup
    #2%
    \def\@currentlabel{#2}%
    \phantomsection\label{#1}\endgroup
}
%% END CROSS-REFERENCING

%% SHORT & LONG TOCs
% daleif - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512752/13492
\newif\ifSHORT
\newif\ifLONG
%
% credit for Ulrike Fischer for this idea, we need to have the
% conditionals defined **inside** the toc
\DeclareRobustCommand\activateif{%
  \let\showShort\ifSHORT
  \let\showLong\ifLONG
  \let\stopShort\fi
  \let\stopLong\fi
}
% next use patching to add a wrapper around the \addcontentsline
% that \tableofcontents generates. Since this is inside a group we
% don't having one patch messing up the other
\newcommand\shortTOC[1][2]{
  \begingroup
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{#1}
  \def\contentsname{\shorttocname}%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{colorsecs}}%
    {\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\color{mychapcolor}\bfseries\sffamily}}%
    {\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\bfseries\sffamily}}%
  \xpatchcmd{\mem@tableofcontents}%
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}}{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\showShort}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\stopShort}%
  }{\typeout{ok}}{\typeout{failed}}
  \LONGtrue
  \tableofcontents
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand\longTOC[1][3]{
  \begingroup
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{#1}
  \def\contentsname{\longtocname}%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{colorsecs}}%
      {\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\color{mychapcolor}\bfseries\sffamily}%
        \renewcommand{\cftsectionfont}{\color{myseccolor}\bfseries\sffamily}%
      }%
      {\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\bfseries\sffamily}%
        \renewcommand{\cftsectionfont}{\bfseries\sffamily}%
      }
  \xpatchcmd{\mem@tableofcontents}%
  {%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}}{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\showLong}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\stopLong}%
  }%
  {\typeout{ok}}{\typeout{failed}}
  \SHORTtrue
  \tableofcontents
  \endgroup
}
% automatically add the activation to the toc
\AtBeginDocument{
  \addtocontents{toc}{\activateif}
}

%% ADD TO USE CHRISTIAN HUPFER'S THIRD METHOD FOR \secref
\providecommand{\LastRefSteppedCounter}{}

\endinput
```

Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to bypass this: if, when I encounter the error, I go to batch mode, then the log shows several  instances of this error...

```
I'm going to ignore the # sign you just used.

./topology.tex:99: You already have nine parameters.
<argument> ...M@sect ####1####2####3####4####5####
                                                  6[####7][####8]####9{\setc...
l.99 \begin{document}
                     
I'm going to ignore the # sign you just used.
```

Then processing continues with some frontmatter (title page, preface) where I get new error on source that previously had no errors!):

```
(./front/preface.tex [10.10

]
Runaway argument?
\@bsphack \edef \@tempa {{page}{\the \c@page }}\setcounter {page}{1}\edef \ETC.
./front/preface.tex:8: Paragraph ended before \cref@old@label was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.8
```

And then into the mainmatter, where many I now get cascading errors from source files that previously compiled without error.

I'd be happy to supply upon request the complete set of preamble files as well as an abbreviated version of the document body source

Comment: It seems that an update to `memoir` didn't go through. It should be fixed very soon.

Comment: @egreg: An update to `memoir` more recent than version 3.7m dates 2020-09-10?

Comment: The relevant code is in `memhfixc.sty`

Comment: @egreg: The `memhfixc.sty` I have is dated 2019/10/24 v1.18, subject "nameref/hyperref package fixes for memoir class" -- so I presume that's the one I need to wait to get an update from CTAN?

Comment: See https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2020-October/046179.html

Comment: you ask `What package(s) broke things, and what is the fix?`  but didn't say which packages you had used, luckily we recognised the error from the mailing list with a real test file, it's memoir (and an update was sent to ctan this evening, so will probably be on ctan tomorrow and texlive in a couple of days)