# pdfpages and linktodoc

Tags: hyperref, links, external-files, pdfpages

I'm trying to link to a specific page in an external document. This has been discussed previously under the topic, [How to link to specified page of an outer pdf document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1021/how-to-link-to-specified-page-of-an-outer-pdf-document), and the answer suggests including the page into this document, and then link to it internally. I'd rather not include the external pages in my document.

I have tried the following from various hints on this site. The following do not work.

```
\href{doc/mydoc.pdf#page=5}{thedoc}
\href{doc/mydoc.pdf#page.5}{thedoc}
\hyperref{foo.pdf}{page}{2}{some text}
\hyperlink{foo.pdf.2}{some text}
```

However, `pdfpages` and the `linktodoc` option to `includepdf` does work both internally **and externally**. I get a copy of a specific page of an external document in my local document, and when I click on that page it jumps to the exact page in the external document. This works with `Preview.app` and `Skim.app` on OS X.

```
\includepdf[pages={2},linktodoc]{foo.pdf}
```

So this is proof it is possible at least with `Preview.app` and/or `Skim.app` to link to specific external pages.

Unfortunately, this link is in the form of an included full page. Is there a way to have this link be some small amount of text of my choosing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `\href` with the new optional argument:

```
\href[page=2]{doc/mydoc.pdf}{thedoc}
```

This requires a relative new version of `hyperref`:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}[2010/09/11]
```

More advanced options exist, like zooming the external PDF. See the `hyperref` manual in section 4 *"Additional user macros"* on page 13.