# How to prevent Table of Contents from being added to the bookmarks of a pdf file

Tags: pdftex, table-of-contents, pdf, bookmarks

I have a set of pdf files (without the latex source) which I merged into a larger pdf file. Each individual pdf file is an article with sections. I created a set of bookmarks for the larger pdf which point to each of the sections in each of the constituent smaller pdf files using the bookmarks package.

```
\bookmark[level=2,page=6,view={FitH 842}]{<Section>}
\bookmark[level=3,page=6,view={FitH \calc{\paperheight-\topmargin-8in} null}]{<Subsection1>}
\bookmark[level=3,page=8,view={FitH \calc{\paperheight-\topmargin-7in} null}]{<Subsection2>}
\bookmark[level=3,page=11,view={FitH \calc{\paperheight-\topmargin-2in} null}]{<Subsection3>}
\bookmark[level=3,page=13,view={FitH \calc{\paperheight-\topmargin-7in} null}]{<Subsection4>}
```

Unfortunately I could not use these bookmarks to create the ToC. To create the ToC I did the following

```
\tableofcontents
\clearpage\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{<Chaptername N>}
\includepdf[pages=-,linktodoc=false]{<file N>.pdf}
\clearpage\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{<Chaptername N+1>}
\includepdf[pages=-,linktodoc=false]{<file N+1>.pdf}
```

The issue I am facing now is that the contents of the ToC are being added (prepended) to the bookmarks data containing the the bookmarks I had manually added.

**My question is: How can I keep the ToC contents from being added to the bookmarks?**

More info:

The ToC data comes before the bookmarks data (the bookmark commands refer to page numbers of the fully merged pdf file). The file structure is as follows:

```
<ToC data>
\bookmarksetup{startatroot}
\bookmarks ...
```

- I need to add the bookmarks because I cannot add the sections of each individual pdf file to the ToC (since I do not have the LaTeX sources)
- The reason I want a separate contents page at the very beginning is because some lightweight pdf readers (such as the google chrome's native pdf reader) do not utilize bookmarks)

This is a continuation of the question I had previously asked at [How do I use LaTeX to create a table of contents for a set of pdf files which I am merging into a single large pdf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12739/how-do-i-use-latex-to-create-table-of-contents-chapter-headings-subsections-etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select to which depth the sectioning commands (part, chapter, section, subsection, etc.) are added as PDF bookmarks using the `depth` package option.
To complete remove them choose the value `-2` or lower (`-1` is for parts, `0` for chapters, ...).

The following example shows the usage. Here only the manually added bookmark is added:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[depth=-1]{bookmark}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\bookmark[level=2,page=2,view={FitH 842}]{Section}
\chapter{Test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\subsubsection{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a ton. I need to read the documentation for the packages more carefully.