# How to prevent duplicate pdf bookmarks from \addcontentsline

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, memoir, bookmarks

I'm creating a LaTeX document with custom-defined sectional headers:

```
\newcommand{\headpart}[1]{\stepcounter{pt}\begin{center}\rule{1.75in}{1pt}\\\vspace{0.5\onelineskip}\Large{Part \thept}\\\vspace{0.25\onelineskip}\large{\textit{#1}}\\\vspace{0.5\onelineskip}\rule{1.75in}{1pt}\\\vspace{2\onelineskip}\end{center}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Part \thept---#1} \renewcommand{\partheadmark}{#1} \label{Part #1} \bookmark[level=1,page=\thepage]{Part \thept---#1}}
\newcommand{\headchap}[1]{\stepcounter{chap}\begin{center}\large{\textbf{\uppercase{Chapter \thechap---#1}}}\end{center}\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Chapter \thechap---#1} \renewcommand{\chapterheadmark}{#1} \label{Chap #1} \bookmark[level=2,page=\thepage]{Chapter \thechap---#1}}
\newcommand{\headsec}[1]{\stepcounter{sec}\vspace{\quarterlineskip}\hangpara{0.5in}{1}\underline{\S \thesec. #1}\vspace{\halflineskip}\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\ifnum \thesec=1 \S \ \else \phantom{\S} \fi \thesec. #1} \renewcommand{\sectionheadmark}{#1} \label{Sec #1} \bookmark[level=3,page=\thepage]{\S \thesec. #1}}
```

I'm using the `hyperref` and `bookmark` packages (in that order) on the `memoir` class. The problem is, the package automatically creates .pdf bookmarks for an entry from `\addcontentsline`. These are never properly set, and I'd like to have the bookmarks defined separately in the headers (As seen above). How can I prevent the package(s) from automatically setting the `\addcontentsline` entries as bookmarks, so it doesn't make duplicates?

Comment: Resolved by [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12804/how-to-prevent-table-of-contents-from-being-added-to-the-bookmarks-of-a-pdf-file)

Comment: Your suggested duplicate: [How to prevent Table of Contents from being added to the bookmarks of a pdf file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12804/how-to-prevent-table-of-contents-from-being-added-to-the-bookmarks-of-a-pdf-file)

Comment: @cfr Never found such a note and even the example in section 2 of the `bookmark` manual loads `hyperref` before `bookmark`. IMHO you don't need to load `hyperref` yourself, but you still can.

Comment: @Adam off-topic: Do you really want to add parts as sections (instead of parts) to the the table of contents?

Comment: @cabohah Huh. You're right. I don't know if something has changed (but, if so, I'm very out-of-date because I checked back to 2020) or if I've always been deluded, but thanks for pointing that out.