# Run a shell script from a PDF generated by LaTeX

Tags: beamer, hyperref, scripts

I have a shell script (which should open some program/file) which I want to invoke by clicking on a link in the generated `.pdf` file (in my case a beamer presentation).

I tried including:

```
\href{run:./Demos/run_demo.sh}{DEMO}
```

in the source code. Then, when clicking on the link (when viewing with acrobat reader) it opens the script in a text editor rather then actually running it. I'm using MacTeX on a Mac OS X system.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This kind of problem could be PDF reader specific. See, for example, [hyperref: How to open a directory view with href{…}?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36567/hyperref-how-to-open-a-directory-view-with-href) and [MacOS X: insert hyperlink to local file (complete path) in LaTeX? (only working with relativ path)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12787/macos-x-insert-hyperlink-to-local-file-complete-path-in-latex-only-working).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On MacOS `run:...` hyperlinks are executed using the `open` command and, hence, processed by the default application configured for the specific file type. For `.sh` files this usually is some text editor.

You can change the default application from the finder (click on an `.sh` file and choose "Get Info"), however, MacOS accepts only "valid applications" (`.app` compartments) as a target, so the Bash or Tcsh binaries cannot easily be defined as default application :-(

Depending on your case a better solution might be to turn the shell script itself into an app and specify this in your `run:` link. This is easily possible using a tool like [Appify](http://sixohthree.com/1314/shell-scripts-as-applications-in-mac-os-x).

Comment: Worked very nicely! Both from `Skim` and `AReader`. One remark though: In the `.sh` script, the path should be absolute rather then relative - otherwise, the generated `.app` bundle doesn't work.

Comment: I'm having the same problem here. I tried using `.command` instead of `.sh` to have the file opened by default by Terminal and it didn't work. I also tried using an applescript saved as a `.app` to run the shell script without more success. I'm using Adobe Reader by the way. It seems that Adobe Reader consider what is in the `run:` command as a file to open, not an app.