# Can programs (e.g. Matlab) be made executable from within the PDF?

Tags: pdf, viewers, attachfile

Is it possible to include a program (as in say Matlab, Maple, etc.) within a LaTeX file in such a way that clicking a button on the resulting PDF file will transport the program to the related software, and run it.

Comment: I'm wondering if you can't use a hyperlink to a shell command: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37719/run-a-shell-script-from-a-pdf-generated-by-latex. In that case you could execute a shell command that can open Matlab and download the file from a webserver or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PDF is a container format, so you *could* embed programs (as you can easily embed files) if these programs allowed distribution via PDF. And you probably *could* program some JavaScript function that tries to execute these embedded files. You will find no viewer that will do this, though: It would be a security hole.

Comment: Can you provide an example? For example how do I transport a segment as a file to some directory (the work space directory of the software which will run the program.) I am after a [TeX-based course management system](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106229/are-there-tex-based-course-management-systems?lq=1)