# Using a system environmental variable in href for a pdf document

Tags: hyperref, environment-variables

Is there a way to use a windows environmental variable in `\href` that uses this environment variable in the output PDF document?

When I use

```
\href{run:\%foo\%\\bar.cpp}{bar.cpp}
```

The PDF Reader I use (Adobe Acrobat Pro) appends `SomeDriveLetter:\` to the front of the link to make

```
SomeDriveLetter:\%foo%\bar.cpp
```

of course this drive does not have the path that foo points to.

Rather, it should go to

```
%foo%\bar.cpp
```

Comment: do you want to look up the environment variable value from within TeX or do you simply want to write a literal `%` and `\ ` into the href?

Comment: No I want the pdf reader to look up the environmental variable value.

Comment: you can use `\@percentchar`  and `\@backslashchar` to get a `%`  and `\ ` but which pdf readers will do anything with a url of the form `run:%foo%` ?

Comment: To clarify, here `%var%` is the Windows/Command Prompt's syntax for environment variable, just like `$var` in bash. ■ So you just need to invoke `cmd` with appropriate arguments (I think the syntax is `cmd /c ⟨command⟩`); however [you can't just pass arguments to `cmd`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244837/run-a-shell-script-with-parameters-from-a-pdf-generated-by-latex?noredirect=1&lq=1) so you need to write a wrapper batch script (Windows shell script) and execute that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. The PDF format does not support environment variables in launch actions.

Comment: Is there a common output format that does support this?

Comment: @LightyearBuzz A shell script (but this is not intended for typesetting).